# KafkaProducer.client.close(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) seemingly blocks forever

Tags: java, apache-kafka, blocking, kafka-producer-api

I just started working with Kafka 2.1.0 today and am exploring the producer API. I have the following code:

```
public class KafkaCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Map<String, Object> cfg = new HashMap<>();
        cfg.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        cfg.put("acks", "all");
        cfg.put("enable.idempotence", true);
        cfg.put("delivery.timeout.ms", 30000);
        final KafkaProducer<String, String> client = new KafkaProducer<>(
                cfg, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());
        try {
            System.out.println("making call");
            client.partitionsFor("veryimportanttopicindeed");
        } catch (KafkaException e) {
            System.out.println("closing");
            client.close(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            throw new RuntimeException("Well this is FUBAR");
        }
    }
}
```

When Kafka is not running, the [partitionsFor](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#partitionsFor-java.lang.String-) call blocks for 60s as expected, but then the [close](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#close-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) call blocks seemingly forever:

```
making call
2018-12-13 15:27:27,955 WARN o.a.k.c.NetworkClient [Producer clientId=producer-1]
Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker
may not be available.
***snip***
closing
2018-12-13 15:28:28,683 WARN o.a.k.c.NetworkClient [Producer clientId=producer-1]
Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. 
Broker may not be available.
***snip***
2018-12-13 15:32:52,667 WARN o.a.k.c.NetworkClient [Producer clientId=producer-1]
Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. 
Broker may not be available.
```

I don't see anything in the [producer configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) that would seem to affect this. How can I get the client to close?

Comment: What are you expecting after close?

Comment: @Deadpool The exception to be thrown, no more logs to be printed, and the process to exit.

Comment: It's a known bug. Please check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7583 for further details.